# Drawing a doughnut chart with columns inside to represent hourly stats in chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, vue-chartjs

This is a chart that represents a stat per hour. This was taken from last.fm website which shows the no. of "scrobbles" (songs played) per hour.

[image: Stats by hour chart]

Is this kind of chart possible with chart.js? I have been able to find a highcharts equivalent of what I am looking for:
[Highcharts Windrose Example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose)

I am already using chart.js within my application and don't want to use 2 libraries to do one job. The closest I have been able to find a chart.js equivalent is this [polar chart](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/polar-area.html)

Can anyone please guide me to a resource that will help me build something like this? Or if you know a better way to represent stat by hour, I am open to that as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be done "out of the box" with chart.js
However chart.js exposed a lot of the canvas api, so you need to write your own chart.js plugin and register a own chart type.